# Symbol display problem

Tags: qgis

I'm using qgis 2.16.  I am attempting to add additional data points (points only, no lines etc.).  The point symbol ( a simple circle) will not display, however the label (the value of the point) will display.  The added point data is added to the Attribute table.  How do I fix this so the points will display?

Comment: There's really not enough information to answer this question. Please describe the whole process you used and add some screenshots along the way.

Comment: did you check the unit used for the symbology? mm, pixels or map units?

Comment: I can be stupid sometimes...I just figured it out,  The point is displaying BEHIND a differing layer, while the Label was in FRONT of the layer...

Comment: Don't worry, it has already happened to everyone at least once... Consider not posting too fast before looking a bit for a solution.